# 502 Bad Gateway with Nginx Reverse Proxy for Docker Flask App

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am having issues creating a reverse proxy to my docker app, which exposes port 5000. Ideally, I want to be able to use a subdomain.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    restart: always
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
    restart: always
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "32000:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drinks
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_USER: my_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password_here
    volumes:
      - my-datavolume:/var/www/mysql
  app:
    restart: always
    build: ./
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
volumes:
  my-datavolume:
```

and here is my DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

# create a new user named marty
RUN adduser -D marty

# current directory where the app will be installed
WORKDIR /home/marty

# copy file from the machine to the container file system
COPY app app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

# run a virtual env and install requirements
RUN python3 -m venv venv
CMD source ./venv/bin/activate
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .pynacl_deps build-base python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# The EXPOSE instruction indicates the ports on which a container # # will listen for connections
# Since Flask apps listen to port 5000  by default, we expose it
EXPOSE 5000

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD python app/app.py
```

Finally, here is my nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

For some reason, I keep getting a `502 Bad gateway` when navigating to api.example.com

I also have already created A records for api. and www.api.

[image: a records]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with Centos 7 and Selinux. I solved this solution by switching to Debian and swearing off Centos forever.

Comment: Had same issue, and `setenforce 0` enabled the requests. I wouldn't put any blame here, and certainly not on CentOS; it is just the way nginx is set up with selinux (not allowing to easily open ports other than 443 and 80). Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I'm having the exact same config but running on Debian, and I'm still having this error :/